# Cannot create new RESTful API Instance

Tags: laravel, api

Doing a small CRUD-App and I'm having problems creating an instance, on Api endpoint: 'event/' the Controller named: EventController and Method: create is called.

This is what the method looks like:

```
public function create(Request $request) {
    $request->validate([
        'title' => 'required|max:30',
        'description' => 'required|max:455',
        'place' => 'required',
        'time_happening' => 'required|date',
    ]);

    $meetup = Event::createFromArray($request->toArray());

    return response()->json($meetup);
}
```

While the model looks like this:

```
public static function createFromArray($data) {

    // Create a new event with the given data.
    $meetup = self::create([
        'title' => $data['title'],
        'description' => $data['description'],
        'place' => $data['place'],
        'time_happening' => $data['time_happening'],
        'created_by' => auth()->user()->id,
        'group_id' => $data['group_id']
    ]);


    // Return the newly created event.
    return $meetup;
}
```

The JSON I'm writing in the API Client:

```
{
  "title": "Laravel Tech Meetup.Laravel Tech Meetup.Laravel Tech 
    Meetup.Laravel Tech Meetup.",

   "description": "Qui molestiae consectetur ipsam vel 
    dicta. Nesciunt architecto laborum accusantium
    eos facere temporibus iure fugiat. 
    Et dicta incidunt ut deleniti eum alias earum.",

   "place": "83224 Blabla",
   "time_happening": "2019-09-25 03:29:46"
}
```

With this code I expect for the new instance to:

1. Get created by the user I'm logged in as,

   2. And to get returned to me in the API Client I'm using(Insomnia)

Result:

I get redirected to Homepage and when I check if it's created in the database it's not.

What am I doing wrong?!

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has few inbuild classes called same as Event

```
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event
\Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Event
```

make sure in top of your EventController you are using correct Event class, Like below

```
use App\Event;
```

Comment: can you please post the error you are getting there?

Comment: There is no error, but when I open my Telescope panel this request is being shown as a GET which confuses me even more- I am only serving the initial route with Laravel, the other ones are being served with Vue Router if that helps

Comment: did you try with the same request using HTTP client like postman?

Comment: Using Postman also redirects me to the initial route(GET method)

Comment: I think your all routes are live inside `web.php` file. change all API related routes to `api.php` file and for Vue application, the only routes lives inside the web.php file look something like this `Route::view('/', 'home');` and `Route::view('/{any}', 'home');`

Comment: That's exactly what I meant in my second comment. First initial route is on web.php, all api routes are on api.php, and all other routes are in the frontend in the routes.js!!!